# "I am having fun with my stay in Japan." Does this phrase sound natural?

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering if this phrase sounds natural.
Also, how about the phrase below?
 "I am having a good time with my stay in Japan."

Do these sentences mean almost the same as "I'm enjoying my stay in Japan." ?

Thx

Comment: No, it doesn't sound natural. You 'have fun with' your companions or with something you are using to amuse yourself, but not your stay. Just say "I'm having a good time in Japan."

Comment: Kate's comment is pretty much it. That isn't how a native speaker would say it anyway. "I'm enjoying my stay in Japan" or "I've been having fun during my stay in Japan" would be better.

Comment: In the context of the Question no, that's not natural and either way, would you not be better off taking that same Question to English Language Learners?